# Vim: w move by subword

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

What's the best way to remap `w`/`W` to stop in the middle of `sub_words` and `subWords`?

I have some text objects installed but I mapping `w` to `vav<esc>` (select next subword and deselect) doesn't get me anywhere.

Help.

Comment: As I remembered Ingo wrote a plugin for this. A CamelCase motion. He is gonna show up soon. :-)

Comment: @Kent Tada! Here I am :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at my [camelcasemotion plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905). It provides motions and text objects for that. You can optionally even replace the built-in `w`, `e`, etc. commands with them!

Comment: God, this is perfect thanks! Guess I didn't use your plugin before because it was in vim-scripts only and looked deserted. Can you please add an option to disable default `,` mappings though?

Comment: If you customize the mappings, the default `,w` etc. mappings won't be defined.

Comment: I did copy all mappings from docs (`wbe` and `iwbe`) but I still can do `,wbe`. https://github.com/firedev/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc

Comment: Does `:verbose nmap ,w` actually list a mapping to camelcasemotion? It might be that the `,` is just ignored (with a beep) by Vim.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, probably was too excited to notice `,w` is actually just `w`.

Comment: Hey Ingo, if you have a word at the end of a line and you do `cw` it deletes the trailing newline as well and joins the next line. Could you please check it?